# How to break loop with ENTER input

Tags: python, list

I want to break this loop when I press ENTER then display the list but it doesn't recognize '' since it has to be a string

```
list = []
while True:
    try:
        num = int(input('Enter integers:'))
        list.append(num)
    except ValueError:
        print('Not an integer, try again')
        continue
    if num == '':
        list.sort()
        print(list)
        break
```

I also want to display "x is not an integer, try again." but I keep getting an error when I try

```
print(num + 'is not and integer, try again.')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're converting it to `int` too early, perform the check and then convert it:

```py
list = []
while True:
    num = input('Enter integers:')
    if num == '':
        list.sort()
        print(list)
        break
    try:
        list.append(int(num))
    except ValueError:
        print('Not an integer, try again')
```

Comment: Consider using another name for `list`.

Answer (score 2):

If you press enter, `num` will be the empty string `''`.

`int('')` raises a `ValueError` which makes the loop `continue` and skip your breaking condidtion.

edit: rearrange your code like in Pedro's answer.

Comment: But this would also print `'Not an integer, try again'`

Comment: @PedroMaia true